# How to get True/False mask from Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, mask, series

I have a pandas Series containing some strings

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

How can I get a serie of True/False based on equality of a string?
For example I want to check the positions of all 'a' and from the example above I want to get as a result

```
True, False, False, False, True
```

Comment: Are you looking for `s == 'a'` ?

Comment: To extend sacul's comment a bit: do a `print(s == 'a')` and you get exactly what you asked for. No need to do a string search.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution in the mean time!

res = s.str.contains("a")

Answer (score -1):

```
np.where(s=='a', 'true', 'false')
```